# Duplicate cells are getting created in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a created a custom cell in iOS.In custom cell there are many labels.For few labels the data of first & fourth custom cell is always same.There are total 5 records in my data source array.Now there are these issues i face.

1. Why cell for row at index is called only two times when there are 4 records in array.
2. Data of first & 4th row is always same.

Please tell me how can i resolve this issue.

**CODE:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell for row called %d",(int)[arr_post count]);
    //define variables here
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributeStr;
    NSAttributedString *attributeStr;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homeCell";
    float x_pos;
   HomeCell *cell = [self.table_view
                     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    //get the post data
    Post *user_post=[arr_post objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.tv_post.text=user_post.post_description;
    cell.tv_post.font = [UIFont fontWithName:user_post.font_family size:[user_post.font_size floatValue]];
    cell.label_name.text=user_post.post_title;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:user_post.modification_date];
    if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {
        x_pos=cell.tv_post.frame.origin.x;
        cell.tv_post_leading_space.constant=-(x_pos);
        [cell.img_post setHidden:true];
    }
    //set the like count
    NSString *first_like_user=user_post.recent_like_name;
    int count=(int)[first_like_user length];
    float like_count=[user_post.like_count intValue];

    //chek if tehre are any likes on the post
    NSLog(@"recent like name is %@",user_post.recent_like_name);
    NSLog(@"like count is %f",like_count);
    if(like_count>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"inside like count block");
        NSString *str_like_count=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)like_count-1];
         if(like_count==1)
        {
            if([myUsername isEqualToString:first_like_user])
            {
                first_like_user=@"You like this post";
                count=3;

            }
            else
            {
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" like this post"];


            }

        }
        else if(like_count==2)
        {
            first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
            str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@" other like this post"];
            first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:str_like_count];

        }
        else
        {
            if(like_count>1000)
            {
                like_count=like_count/1000;
                str_like_count=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)like_count];
                str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@"k"];
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
                str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@" others like this post"];
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:str_like_count];


            }
            else
            {
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
                str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@" others like this post"];
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:str_like_count];

            }


        }
        mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:first_like_user];
        attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

        [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
        [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

        [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];

        //set the like label dynamic height & width
        cell.label_like_count.attributedText = mutableAttributeStr;
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(187,9999);
        CGSize requiredSize = [cell.label_like_count sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
        CGRect labelFrame = cell.label_like_count.frame;
        labelFrame.size.height = requiredSize.height;
        cell.label_like_count.frame = labelFrame;
        //  cell.label_like_count.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.label_like_count.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.label_like_count sizeToFit];
        [cell.label_like_count setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
    }
    //show dynamic comment
    NSMutableArray *user_comments=user_post.comments;
    float comment_count=[user_post.comment_count intValue];
    NSLog(@"arr comments count is %lu",(unsigned long)comment_count);
    if(comment_count>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"post id is %@",user_post.id);
        NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributeStr;
        NSAttributedString *attributeStr;
        for(l=0;l<[user_comments count];l++)
        {
            NSLog(@"inside loop %d",l);
            Comment *comment=[user_comments objectAtIndex:l];
            if(l==0)
            {
                NSLog(@"l is zero");
                NSString *comment_string=[comment.user_name stringByAppendingString:@" "];
                comment_string=[comment_string stringByAppendingString:comment.comment];
                int count=(int)[comment.user_name length];
                mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:comment_string];
                NSLog(@"comment string is %@",comment_string);
                attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

                [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];
                [cell.first_comment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];


            }
            else if(l==1)
            {
                 NSLog(@"l is 1");
                NSString *comment_string=[comment.user_name stringByAppendingString:@" "];
                comment_string=[comment_string stringByAppendingString:comment.comment];
                int count=(int)[comment.user_name length];
                mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:comment_string];

                attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
                NSLog(@"comment string is %@",comment_string);
                [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];
                [cell.second_cmment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
            }
            else if(l==2)
            {
                 NSLog(@"l is 2");
                NSString *comment_string=[comment.user_name stringByAppendingString:@" "];
                comment_string=[comment_string stringByAppendingString:comment.comment];
                int count=(int)[comment.user_name length];
                mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:comment_string];

                attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

                [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];
                [cell.third_comment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];

            }



        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not inside loop");

    }

    cell.label_time.text=[BaseController getTimestampForDate:date];
    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have read somewhere that for performance reasons UITable resume the cell.Because i feel i get this issue when there are more than 3 rows.

**EDIT:**
I have found a strange situation here if i try don't use the condition `if(like_count>0)` & simply set the text fo label with out this condition then it works fine for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain bit more in detail. like code or image or etc.

Comment: Please post your codes and leave the "xcode" tag alone.

Comment: Ooh.. You gotta refactor that `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` a lot of work for a single method, try practicing MVC pattern..

Comment: sugesst some in my code

Comment: @TechGuy, hmm. okay. later i'll help you refactor and solve your issue. For now: for your first question, check your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` make sure it is returning the correct value.

Comment: from tableView:numberOfRowsInSection what are you returning? 
You should your dataSource(type of array, dictionary).count.

Comment: i am returning the count of the array which has all data

Comment: are you sure it has all the data? If you log the count of it, what does it return?

Comment: it return 5.it has got all the data.check my edit in question

Comment: yes, i have seen it. The problem is that, that the count of indexPath starts with 0, not 1 ! Same for array counts.

You should remove that for sure. The first cells indexPath is [0 : 0]

Comment: @TechGuy: The problem is you are not assigning values under `else`. Default values perhaps.

Comment: can you post the code with answer@0yeoj

Comment: i did not undestand@dirtydanee

Comment: Please suggest some solution here.

Comment: @TechGuy do you have demo...so I can properly test and understand things :)

Comment: share  your email address i can mail you.I won't be able to prepare demo now

Comment: Share number of row  and section methods too means more help-full

Comment: It would really help to see a screenshot.

Comment: Seriously, Your code is too big to be executed in cellForRow. Try some refactoring using MVC Patterns as suggested by @Oyeoj, and also practice using prepareForReuse method for your custom cells.

Comment: what to write inside prepareForReuse method.Please tell.

Comment: try to replace static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homeCell"; with NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homeCell";. Just Remove static.

Comment: Also don't forget to add "else" part of the if statements to avoid partial duplications. Example:

    if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {
        [cell.img_post setHidden:true];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.img_post setHidden:false];
    }

Answer (score 5):

Cell are reused, so you have to cover all case in your execution path.

As you already found, `if(like_count>0)` and `if(comment_count>0)` imply that if there is no count, the text label is not changed and the old value will stay there.

You have to add `} else { cell.label_like_count.attributedText = nil }` kind of code to cover all cases. Alternatively, you can add some cleanup code in `- (void)prepareForReuse` in the cell class (don't forget `[super prepareForReuse]`).

Comment: Using prepareForReuse is a good place to clean up the cells for next use.

Answer (score 1):

in `HomeCell` override `prepareForReuse:`. In that method, set the `.text` (or `.attributedText`) property to `nil` on all of your labels. Then see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Cells are reused and the table always creates only the cells that are currently visible. When you show the screen, three cells will be visible. When you scroll and one cell becomes hidden and another one appears, it's actually the same cell instance.

The usual way to handle this behavior is to subclass `UITableViewCell` and do all that setup there. The reset to a default state can be added to `-prepareForReuse` method, e.g.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
   [super prepareForReuse];

   self.first_comment.text = nil;
   self.second_comment.text = nil;
   self.third_comment.text = nil;
}
```

To fix your code without having a specific cell subclass, let's first simplify by removing the repetitive patterns from your code:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [user_comments count]; i++) { //i is the traditional variable name for iterating
    Comment *comment = user_comments[i]; //updating to newer syntax

    // start of the repetitive pattern
    NSString *comment_string=[comment.user_name stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    comment_string=[comment_string stringByAppendingString:comment.comment];
    int count=(int)[comment.user_name length];
    NSMutableAttributedString* mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:comment_string];

    NSAttributedString attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

    [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
    [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

    [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];
    // end of the repetitive pattern

    if (i == 0) {
        [cell.first_comment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
    }
    else if (i == 1) {
        [cell.second_comment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
    }
    else if (i == 2) {
        [cell.third_comment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
    }
}
```

Now you can combine it with resetting the value:

```
NSArray *commentLabels = @[cell.first_comment, cell.second_comment, cell.third_comment];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    UILabel *label = commentLabels[i];

    // reset if there is no comment
    if (i >= [user_comments count]) {
        label.text = nil;
        continue;
    }

    Comment *comment = user_comments[i];

    NSString *comment_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", comment.user_name, comment.comment];
    int count = (int)[comment.user_name length];
    NSMutableAttributedString* mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:comment_string];

    NSAttributedString attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

    [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0 range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
    [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

    [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];

    label.attributedText = mutableAttributeStr;
}
```

Comment: actuallu i am not creating labels at run time

Comment: @TechGuy I just took your code, simplified it (without changing functionality) and then added a reset that was missing in your original code.

Comment: Well this won't solve the issue but it may improve the code readability

Comment: Why this will solve issue?you have just divided into steps

Comment: @TechGuy I added that `label.text = nil;` which will reset the cell if there are no comments.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of elements in the table and be sure the number is correct in the delegate **numberOfRowsInSection**:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return the_correct_items_number;
}
```

If the count is correct, try with a local array (just for test). Note: if you update the source array using network requests, consider to use the dispatch_async calling to update you content.

Comment: number of section return 5 which is the size of array

Comment: OK, sorry... sometimes this happen but probably is not your case

Comment: can you suggest me something else by looking at th code

Comment: The only thing that I can say is If the function is called only 2 times instead 4 , probably there is something wrong in the count of elements in the array (somewhere in your code you change the number of array while your are updating the table) .. but I see you also log the elements count... is very strange....

Comment: for me also strange.Actually i am reloading the data when data is fetched from the network.

Comment: Have you tried to create a simulated array as source... a simple array created in only one point in the code (example in viewdidload)? Just to test if the table is correctly created?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92132/discussion-between-lorenzo-and-techguy).

Comment: i am getting the data from server when i get all the data then i call the function **[self.table_view reloadData];**

Answer (score 0):

Use methods `prepareForReuse` in your custom cell .

// if the cell is reusable (has a reuse identifier), this is called just before the cell is returned from the table view method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:.  If you override, you MUST call super.

```
- (void) prepareForReuse {

 // set empty or nil of your repeated element .

 [super prepareForReuse];
}
```

hope it help you .

Answer (score -1):

try replacing

```
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[HomeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

with

```
//if (cell==nil)
//{
    cell = [[HomeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
// }
```

Answer (score -1):

After you dequeue cell, write the below line:-

```
[cell.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: i read somewhere for performance it refuses the cell so it may be the issue

Comment: This will not be the case. For performances related issue, the app hangs or memory warning received. Have you implement the code that I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I am saying iOS reuse the cells once it has been created because i get duplicate cells when i scroll down to screen.On scrolling each time the **cellForRowAtIndex** is called each time